# How to do "pull requests" with a remote Git repository on a Windows file share?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Not even sure if this is possible, but I'd like to be able perform a "pull request" with a git repository hosted on a Windows file share in the same way you would with a repo on github.  If this is doable, how?

btw, I'm using msysgit client on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: What about placing a git repo in some public area, and mail somebody so he merge the branch to main repo?

Comment: We have a rather small team so that is doable.  I was just wondering, given that the remote repo is on a Windows share, if there was a way to replicate the "pull request" feature offered via github.